# how to use @job in odoo v15 queue_job?

Tags: python, odoo

In odoo v13 i use @job with 'from addons.queue_job.job import job, related_action'
but now in odoo 15 I do not know how  so  how to use @job in odoo v15 queue_job  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decorator was removed, the PR with some more information is found [here](https://github.com/OCA/queue/pull/274).

So you need to write XML records for model `queue.job.function` like

```xml
<record id="job_function_sale_order_action_done" model="queue.job.function">
    <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"</field>
    <field name="method">action_done</field>
    <field name="channel_id" ref="channel_sale" />
    <field name="related_action" eval='{"func_name": "custom_related_action"}' />
    <field name="retry_pattern" eval="{1: 60, 2: 180, 3: 10, 5: 300}" />
</record>
```

This example is from the [modules readme for version 15.0](https://github.com/OCA/queue/tree/5fe8275131dcba1d8b23d602ab75d3051c8e4bdd/queue_job).

Comment: thank you , so now i add this record XML ? I no longer need to use @job

Comment: In 15 it was completely removed, so `@job` is not usable anymore.

Comment: An important precision is that the XML definition is not mandatory. Using it allows you to configure options such as the channel, related action, ... But you can really use any method as job, even without the XML entry.

Comment: That's correct.